# CORS preflight channel did not succeed, React to Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors

When sending a request over CORS from my React app to my Node.JS and Express.js backend i get an:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3001/students/login. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).
```

Im using axios for sending out requests and this is the request configuration:

```
({ email, password }) => {
        return axios.post(API_ENDPOINT + UCENIK.post.login,
            { email, password },
            {
                withCredentials: true,
                Headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                }
            })
    }
```

I have tried allowing CORS in Express with these headers:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.headers.origin);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization')");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    next();
});
```

Edit: fixed using npm Cors module and providing this object for settings:

```
{
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    cors: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is only a development problem,  because your express instance and reactjs  frontend server run on a different port. In the production environment this probably isn't the case.

In stead of using CORS in your development cycle try to proxy the request from your frontend server to your express server.

For exmple the webpack devserver has a seperate proxy configuration https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy